# SQL hungarian case sensitive

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to save usernames in my database. I used to use `utf8_hungarian_ci` but ofc that was case insensitive. I wanted to change it to `utf8_hungarian_cs` but there isn't such an option in phpmyadmin. I'm using `latin1_general_cs` at the moment, which works fine, but any data with accent looks like this in my db: `tÃ©szta`

So the question is, how can I use hungarian collation as case sensitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try with `utf8mb4_hu_0900_as_cs`.
They have it in [MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-mysql.html).